# Add Product Thumbnail to My Account - Recent Orders - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering if there is a way to add a product thumbnail into the buyer's 'Recent Orders' page in 'My Account' in Woocommerce frontend.

I've being trying to find some sort of solution, but no luck whats so ever.

I haven't tried anything to give you a code, just because I have no idea how to 
actually go about this.

Would someone be able to point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to edit `templates/myaccount/my-orders.php`. Add the following code to where you want the thumbnails to show.

```
<?php 
    // Get a list of all items that belong to the order
    $products = $order->get_items();

    // Loop through the items and get the product image
    foreach( $products as $product ) {                  

        $product_obj = new WC_Product( $product["product_id"] );

        echo $product_obj->get_image();

    }
?>
```

Comment: I am gald I could help :) Happy coding.

Comment: @UpendraSharma : as explained in the answer, add it to where you want the thumbnails to show, just ensure that you add it inside the `foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {` loop

Comment: @AnandShah : i added this but it is showing only thumnail not the actual image

Comment: @UpendraSharma, you can pass the image size to `get_image` , the default is `shop_thumbnail` , so if you need the large image use `echo $product_obj->get_image( 'large' );`