# Get Product Permalink - My Account - Recent Orders Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've been trying to add a product thumbnail image linking to product on customer Recent Orders page, My Account in woocommerce. 
I have managed to get the Image Thumbnail in place thanks to Anand from this question here : 
[Add Product Thumbnail to My Account - Recent Orders - Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546192/add-product-thumbnail-to-my-account-recent-orders-woocommerce), 
but now I'm strugling to make this thumb a permalink that links to the actual product.

So I know that this is the code to get the image thumbnail in place :

```
<?php 
    // Get a list of all items that belong to the order
    $products = $order->get_items();

    // Loop through the items and get the product image
    foreach( $products as $product ) {                  

        $product_obj = new WC_Product( $product["product_id"] );

        echo $product_obj->get_image();

    }
?>
```

I've been trying to turn the thumbnail into a permalink like this :

```
<?php 
   // Get a list of all items that belong to the order
   $products = $order->get_items();

   // Loop through the items and get the product image
   foreach( $products as $product ) {                  

   $product_obj = new WC_Product( $product["product_id"] );

   echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'"><?php echo $product_obj->get_image();?></a>';

   }
 ?>
```

Or like this :

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">'echo $product_obj->get_image()'</a>';
```

Or this :

```
<a href="<?php echo $url = get_permalink( $product_id ); ?>">
    <?php 
           // Get a list of all items that belong to the order
           $products = $order->get_items();

           // Loop through the items and get the product image
           foreach( $products as $product ) {                  

           $product_obj = new WC_Product( $product["product_id"] );

           echo $product_obj->get_image();

        }
     ?>
```

But just can't seem to be anywhere near .. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple, the Product class has a `get_permalink` method which you can use like so:

```
$product_obj = new WC_Product( $product["product_id"] );

$link = $product_obj->get_permalink();

echo '<a href="'. $link .'">' . $product_obj->get_image() . '</a>';
```

**EDIT**

If you however want to use the `get_permalink` offered by WordPress you can do it like so

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_obj->id).'"><?php echo $product_obj->get_image();?></a>';
```

You were using `$product_id` in your code below, since its not defined anywhere your code wasn't working. You were very close :)

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'"><?php echo $product_obj->get_image();?></a>';
```

Comment: works great! Once again, thanks so much, you've been a really great help!

Comment: Happy to help :) happy coding